# DJANGO: Product matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django

[image: Код ошибки]Не пойму в чём дело.
Выбивает ошибку:
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/basket-add/12/
Django Version: 3.2.4
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:
Product matching query does not exist.

Добавляю элемент так:

```
def basket_add(request, product_id):
    current_page = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    baskets = Basket.objects.filter(user=request.user, product=product)
    if not baskets.exists():
       
        Basket.objects.create(user=request.user, product=product, quantity=1)
        return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(current_page)
    else:
        basket = baskets.first()
        basket.quantity += 1
        basket.save()
        return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(current_page)
```

Удаляю

```
def basket_delete(request, id):
    basket = Basket.objects.get(id=id)
    basket.delete()
    return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

В шаблоне:

```
    <a href="{% url 'products:basket_delete' basket.id %}" style="text-decoration: none; color: gray;">
        <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
    </a>
```

URLs:

```
from django.urls import path
from products.views import products, basket_add, basket_delete

app_name = 'products'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', products, name="index"),
    path('basket-add/<int:product_id>/', basket_add, name="basket_add"),
    path('basket-add/<int:id>/', basket_delete, name="basket_delete"),
]
```

Модели (на всякий случай все скинул, мало ли где то ранее накосячил)

```
from django.db import models
from users.models import User

class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Product Categories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products_images', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    category = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}  ({self.category.name})"


class Basket(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    created_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Корзина для {self.user.username} | Продукт {self.product.name}"
```

Делаю точно по курсам, всё 1 в 1 (единственное, что версия джанги старее) и такое.
[image: БД корзины]
[image: БД продуктов]

Comment: Product.objects.get(id=product_id) . А в бд точно есть продукт с таким id?

Comment: Миграцию сделал?

Comment: @Alpensin , да, я по курсам делал, всё как там и не понятно почему у меня так -.-

Comment: @SergeiMalanin , да

Comment: Добавь в описание код с моделями пожалуйста.

Comment: @SergeiMalanin , да, конечно. Добавил.

Comment: Добавил содержимое БД